# How do I initialize an empty array when using a typescript alias?

Tags: typescript

I declare a type alias but cannot initialize it without creating an item:

`type ModelState = [string, string[]];`
`const modelState: ModelState = [null,[]];`
`modelState["firstName"] = ["First name is required."];`

TypeScript gives me an error "Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[string, string[]]'" if I try to initialize like this:

`const modelState: ModelState = [];`

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should initialize the tupel with data, but you can trick the compiler like this:

```
const modelState: ModelState = [] as any;
```

A tupel in in the form of `[string, string[]]` would still be an array with numerical index though. It looks to me that you actuall want something like this:

```
interface ModelState {
    firstName: string[],
    lastName: string[],
}
```

Or maybe even like this:

```
interface ModelState {
    [key: string]: string[],
}
```

Comment: `const modelState: ModelState = [] as any;` should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Initializing like this has problems:

`const modelState: ModelState = [] as any;`

Try adding a key value pair:

`modelState["firstName"] = ["First name is required."];`

`console.log(JSON.stringify(modelState));`

The JSON object remains empty.

If I initialize like this and add the key/value it works as expected.

`const modelState: ModelState = {};`

Also typescript reports an error if the value is not an array of strings. Doesn't report a problem if the key is not a string however.

Not sure if I can say this is intuitive but it works.